# Limiting the number of matches in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j scenario (I am using Neo4j 2.0.1):

Nodes:

```
User
Token
```

Relationships:

```
friends_with -> bidirectional relationship between Users
is_authorized_by -> directed relationship between a User and a Token
```

For each User, I need to get either its Token (if it has a valid one), or a valid friend's Token.

I've written the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN ['123', '456'] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (user_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < user_token.expiration_timestamp 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:friends_with*1..3]-(friend:User)-[:is_authorized_by]->(friend_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (friend_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < friend_token.expiration_timestamp  
RETURN user.id as userId, coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token
```

Of course, this doesn't work, as the second OPTIONAL MATCH doesn't only match the first friend's Token.

What I would like to do is:

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN ['123', '456'] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (user_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < user_token.expiration_timestamp 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:friends_with*1..3]-(friend:User)-[:is_authorized_by]->(friend_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (friend_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < friend_token.expiration_timestamp  <--- limit this to 1
RETURN user.id as userId, coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token
```

How can this be achieved?

**Edit 1:**

I'm only interested in direct friends' Tokens:

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN ['123', '456'] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (user_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < user_token.expiration_timestamp 
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:friends_with]-(friend:User)-[:is_authorized_by]->(friend_token:Token) 
    WHERE HAS (friend_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < friend_token.expiration_timestamp  
RETURN user.id as userId, coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token
```

Comment: Please note that the `user.id IN ['123', '456']` is not yet an efficient operation. Only equality so far for index lookups

Comment: How many rows does this return? Would you want to limit it to one too?

`OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token)`

Do you want one token per friend or only one friend-token in total?

Comment: @MichaelHunger A User always has exactly one Token. I can authorize an User either by using his own Token or the Token of a direct friend. In the end, I want to return one valid Token for each User, preferring the User's own Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just return any one out of the returned list you can apply an aggregation function like MAX, i.e.

> RETURN user.id as userId, MAX (coalesce(user_token.access_token,
>   friend_token.access_token)) AS token

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I'm afraid the query might end up traversing the whole graph. Is this right?

Comment: It just traverses user friends, not the whole graph.

Comment: good observation, I should only look for tokens of direct friends anyway. But what would you recommend: 1. running a query for each individual user and using WITH and LIMIT or 2. running this query for multiple users, expecting some performance penalty for traversing all friends?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question? I don't get exactly the point.

Comment: Running -- `MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id ='123' OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token) WHERE HAS (user_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < user_token.expiration_timestamp OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:friends_with]-(friend:User)-[:is_authorized_by]->(friend_token:Token) WHERE HAS (friend_token.access_token) AND timestamp()/1000 < friend_token.expiration_timestamp WITH user_token, friend_token LIMIT 1 RETURN coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token` -- should stop after first friend_token match, right?

Comment: Yes but but anyway the graph is traversed, limit is applied only after the WITH clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `coalesce()` function already returns at most one `access_token`, you simply want to return just one row per `userId`:

```
RETURN DISTINCT user.id as userId, coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token
```

Comment: Running a profile on the query seems to reveal that this too first traverses the graph before applying "DISTINCT". Would it be possible to do it in a way that actually stops upon discovering the first friend_token?

Comment: @user3455402 If the user has more friends with valid tokens, this query even with distinct returns one row for each distinct friend token

Comment: @remigio valid point! just out of curiosity, is there any way to specify DISTINCT per column?

Comment: I'm not sure to get the point, can you make an example of DISTINCT per column?

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does this return? Would you want to limit it to one too?

`OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(user_token:Token)`

Do you want one token per friend or only one friend-token in total?

Your tokens also don't seem to be connected at all? So you probably also rather want do something like this? Just guessing, not sure if that will perform as you'd like.

```
MATCH (user:User {id:'123'})
WITH user, head(filter(token in 
          extract(p in (user)-[:is_authorized_by]->(:Token) | last(nodes(p))) 
          WHERE token.access_token AND timestamp()/1000 < token.expiration_timestamp)) as user_token
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[:friends_with*1..3]-(friend:User)
WITH user, user_token, 
     head(filter(token in 
          extract(p in (friend)-[:is_authorized_by]->(:Token) | last(nodes(p))) 
          WHERE token.access_token AND timestamp()/1000 < token.expiration_timestamp)) as friend_token
RETURN user.id as userId, coalesce(user_token.access_token, friend_token.access_token) AS token
```

Comment: This seems close to what I need. A User always has exactly one Token. I can authorize a User either by using his own Token or the Token of a direct friend. In the end, I want to return one valid Token for each User, preferring the User's own Token. The Tokens are not related to each other. I need to return pairs of "user ids" - "valid access tokens". In your case, I'm looking only to return "123" - "a valid token for 123". In my original scenario, I searched for both users with ids "123" and "456", so I wanted to return two rows: "123" - "valid token for 123" and "456" - "valid token for 456".

Comment: For now, running the query returns: "Don't know how to treat that as a predicate: xyz", where xyz is a Token.access_token